# Videos not displayed in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, video, video-player

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Lenovo machine, having 1.5 GB of RAM and a wide screeen LCD Dell monitor (I think videos have a 16:9 aspect ratio).

The problem is  I am  not able to see videos in VLC or Totem movie players.
I'm able to listen to sound, but videos are not displayed.

SMPlayer is working well to display video.

Could anyone please explain to me how to play videos in other media player?

Answer (score 1):

- It might be the case that proper codecs are not installed.

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Enter your password when prompted.

- If this doesn't solve the problem, you might need to install the appropriate drivers.

  - To install the drivers, go to *System Settings* > *Additional Drivers*. You should be able to see the drivers that need to be installed.
  - If you can't see anything, download the drivers from the vendor's website.

Comment: is dell monitors driver available for ubuntu ?

Comment: it depends on the graphic card. What is the output of `lspci | grep VGA`?

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 661/741/760 PCI/AGP or 662/761Gx PCIE VGA Display Adapter
vijay@vijay-LEGEND-Dragon-Mob914Set:~$ ^C

Comment: did you try installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: ubuntu-restricted-extras are already installed, codec is not problem. i think it is resolution problem.